# How can I reload data in UItableviewCell after I download data for each cell from internet?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsurlsession

I have a tableview with some cells and each cell will get data from internet.
my function for my tableviewcell like this:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("placeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WeatherTableViewCell

                ......

        //Create Url here...
                ......

        let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
                //                println("dataObject:\(dataObject)")

                .........

        // Got data text here

                .........

                println("dataText: \(self.dataText)")


            }
            cell.label.text = "\(self.dataText)"


        })
        downloadTask.resume()

        return cell
    }
```

EveryThing working fine , I can got all the data for each cell but cell's label does not update the dataText. 
I want cell update the dataText when I got the data for each cell. How can I do that?

Comment: You should update the label on main thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to update your UI in the main thread.
replace this:

```
cell.label.text = "\(self.dataText)"
```

With this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        cell.label.text = "\(self.dataText)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this.

```
var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve your requirements using below code as well

```
// on main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // do your background code here
        // schedule data download here

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // on main thread
            // assign the text to label here
            // also be sure to assign the text to label of current index path cell
        });
    });


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343678/how-can-i-reload-data-in-uitableviewcell-after-i-download-data-for-each-cell-fro?answertab=oldest#tab-top
```